# angularfire not working with me , I don't know why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

the html code - which call the required libraries

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="seworko">
            <div ng-controller="users">
                {{ 4+4 }}
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the Javascript code

```
    var app = angular.module("seworko", ["firebase"]);

    var config = {
    apiKey:"myKey",
    authDomain:"myDomain.firebaseio.com",
    databaseURL:"https://myUrl.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket:"myBucket.com"};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

app.controller("users", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    try
        {
            const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('system');
            const ref = rootRef.child('global');
            this.global = $firebaseObject(ref);
        }
    catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);//type error a.ref is not a function
        }
});
```

I am getting this error -> 
type error a.ref is not a function !!

I don't know the reason for the error
I followed too many tutorials , and can't connect firebase with angularJS using angularfire

Comment: I tested your code and it's ok....but with an older version of firebase (firebase 2.3.1)....also make sure to edit your api info!!!

Comment: Hi , I changed it to version 2.3.1 , and to this code : http://pastebin.com/24tuA0ae -- also I'm getting this error
:-> ReferenceError : firebase is not defined

Comment: @Hackerman ????

Comment: Wait....I have pastebin blocked on my work-place....I am trying to make it work on codepen...just wait a bit

Comment: here's the code : http://freetexthost.com/n1i1j26hnb

Comment: Also blocked lol...but, look, if you look at this, it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKdQrz?editors=1111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123971/discussion-between-ahmed-mohsen-and-hackerman).

Comment: I have the chat blocked too xD

Comment: your code will work normally , but what about the firebase configs ? , this code firebase.initializeApp(config); // makes this error :- ReferenceError : firebase is not defined

Comment: I have it working right now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKdQrz

Comment: it makes the same errors I mentioned in this post
these codes makes this error:-TypeError: a.ref is not a function


const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('system');
            const ref = rootRef.child('global');
            this.global = $firebaseObject(ref);

Comment: I was able to track down the error...the error happens on this line `his.global =$firebaseObject(ref)`

Comment: Working without that line: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKdQrz

Comment: Are you putting your code through a minifier by any chance?

Comment: I just discovered that $firebaseObject is not compatible with firebase 3.0...but you can use $firebaseArray instead and should works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKdQrz...right now if you see the browser console is giving me a message "permission_denied at /system/global: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data" and makes sense because the codepen domain is not authorized to acces your data....